# (Entropy) Surprise of observing two independent events $A$ and $B$ (or observe $A \cap B$)

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

I saw the following explanation:

> (Entropy). The surprise of learning that an event with probability $p$ happened is defined as $\log_2(1/p)$, measured in a unit called bits. Low-probability events have high surprise, while an event with probability $1$ has zero surprise. The $\log$ is there so that if we observe two independent events $A$ and $B$, the total surprise is the same as the surprise from observing $A \cap B$. The $\log$ is base $2$ so that if we learn that an event with probability $1/2$ happened, the surprise is $1$, which corresponds to having received $1$ bit of information.

So if we do observe two independent events $A$ and $B$ (or observe $A \cap B$), then what does the $\log$ look like? In other words, what is the mathematics of such a case? We have that $H(X) = \sum_\limits{j = 1}^n p_j \log_2(1/p_j)$ for a single discrete r.v. $X$ whose distinct possible values are $a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n$, with probabilities $p_1,p_2 ...,p_n$ respectively (so $p_1 + p_2 + ··· + p_n = 1$). And if $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ for independent random variables $A$ and $B$, then would it be $H(A \cap B) = \sum_\limits{i = 1}^n \sum_\limits{j = 1}^n p_i p_j\log_2(1/p_i) \log_2(1/p_j)$, or something of the sort? Thank you.

Comment: The point of using a logarithm is that log(ab)= log(a)+ log(b). If A and B are independent events, probability that A happens is a, and probability that B happens is b, then the probability that **both** A and B happen ($A\cap B$) is ab.  Therefore the "surprise" that both A and B happen is the sum of the "surprises" of A and B separately:  $log_2(1/ab)= log_2((1/a)(1/b)= log_2(1/a)+ log_2(1/b)$.

Comment: @user247327 Ok, I understand. Thanks for that!

Comment: Your definition of entropy is not correct! $H(X)=\sum \limits_{j=1}^n p_j \log_2(1/p_j)$.

Comment: @Mini Thanks. Main post edited.